# Samba through AD not working

Tags: samba

I'm trying to get a samba to work with a windows AD. And i can't use my shares through samba.

My smb.conf

```
#GLOBAL PARAMETERS
[global]
   workgroup = MY_DOMAIN
   realm = MY_DOMAIN.COM
   preferred master = no
   server string = Linux Test Machine
   security = ADS
   encrypt passwords = yes
   password server = MY_MASTER_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER
   log level = 3
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m
   max log size = 50
   printcap name = cups
   printing = cups
   winbind enum users = Yes
   winbind enum groups = Yes
   winbind use default domain = Yes
   winbind nested groups = Yes
   winbind separator = +
   idmap uid = 1100-20000
   idmap gid = 1100-20000
   ;template primary group = "Domain Users"
   template shell = /bin/bash



[homes]
   comment = Home Direcotries
   valid users = %S
   read only = No
   browseable = No

[tmp]
   comment = Directory for storing pictures by jims users
   path= /var/tmp
   Valid Users = @"MY_DOMAIN+group name" MY_DOMAIN+MY_ACCOUNT
  ; public=no
   writable=yes
   browseable=yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
```

wbinfo -u and wbinfo -g work as expected.  kinit MY_ACCOUNT@MY_DOMAIN.COM works too.

But i can't connect to samba.  I'm using debian 5, samba 3.2.5 and kerberos 5. My /var/www is 777.  Any ideas ?

Comment: You'd get more help with Server/Daemon questions at ServerFault.

Comment: Following you advice i add a post on unix.stackoverflow

Comment: Don't cross post. Your question can be migrated.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a backend to connect to AD.

```
idmap config MY_DOMAIN:default = true
idmap config MY_DOMAIN:schema-mode = rfc2307
idmap config MY_DOMAIN:range = 10000-49999
idmap config MY_DOMAIN:backend = ad
idmap config * : backend = tdb
idmap config * : range = 50000-99999
winbind nss info = rfc2307
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to set this question to solved. I did suceed to connect.  I don't remember exactly how I solved the problem, but it was in the kerberos client. It was a problem with an AD alias.